# File converter make strange numbers in output

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics, numba

I have a code, that converts .vcf files to eigenstrat files. On my laptop works perfectly, but becasue of the memory usage, I need to use it on our servers, but on the server, I don't know why i get this strange numbers, the file should only contain 0 or 1 or 2. I uploaded my code here:
https://github.com/Galmadeus/VCf_to_eigen
Why is this happen, and how could i solve it? (Laptop is Win10, Server is Linux)

```
...2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-9223372036854775808-...
```

Comment: `-9223372036854775808` is the largest negative number that fits in 64 bits.  Is it possible your code is dividing 0 by 0?  That will produce negative infinity, which will result in this.

Comment: And this solved the problem. Somehow when i concat the two dataframe, it changes datatype of a few column, and that caused the problem.